# Adding a existing (raid) harddisk to esxi without data loss

Tags: vmware-esxi, hard-drive, ubuntu-12.04, vmware-vsphere

My previous install was an Ubuntu-Server 12.04 installation without VMWare.
There i had 1 OS disk with 750GB and 2 other disks (both 2TB) in RAID1.

I decided to virtualize my server so i can add more vm's and also have more controll over them.

So the installation of esxi went fine but to prevent data loss i unplugged the 2 data disks and just installed everything on the 750GB disk.
The problem now is that i want to add the RAID Disks back without data loss so i can mount them in 1 of the VM's

I just cant find a way to add them without the disks getting wiped.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Using ESXI 5.1 btw
EDIT2: Used a software raid

Answer (score 1):

Plug the disks in and do whatever you need to in your BIOS/RAID controller to provision them. Consult the manual of your server if you're unsure of what this means.

Then rescan for storage within ESXi and add the discovered storage as a datastore. It is non-destructive.

Comment: Ah i would like to thank you for your answer but i forgot to mention that i use a software raid, and apparently esxi doesnt support software raid.

Comment: If your RAID controller is not on the VMware HCL, then you will not be able to use it. ESXi is not meant to run on any general purpose system, it is meant to run on a specific set of server-grade hardware. If your hardware isn't on the HCL, your only option is to replace it.

Comment: My hardware is supported though but i think can come to the conclussion that i have to find a way to backup one of the disks and just save the data on another medium untill i added both disks to the esxi and then just software raid it within the guest os.